# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'server/simple_server'

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Every time I do a `git pull` from SourceTree, I receive the following message:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree submodule update --init --recursive

No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'server/simple_server'

Completed with errors, see above
```

However, preceding the above message, the pull works as expected and everything is fine (code pulls, auto-merge, etc works as expected). This happens for every repo I've cloned using SourceTree. If I use the CLI to do a `git pull`, no submodule checks are performed and so I never see the above ('error') message. Why is SourceTree performing this extra step in the git pull (which does not happen from the CLI). I've gone through every possible option in SourceTree preferences.
I'm running SourceTree on a Mac now, but I had a (Windows) PC last week (and prior) running SourceTree and received the same errors – this appears to be a (default) feature of `git pull` in SourceTree, regardless of platform. And, once again, only happens via the GUI, not CLI – on all of my cloned repos.
Any advice would be appreciated. I hate seeing a false negative in my git pulls while using SourceTree.

Comment: The repo, in SourceTree must be setup to not auto-check submodules. After re-creating the repos, I eliminated the problem (the solution is to un-check the box requiring repos to be auto-checked for submodules). However, I believe may situation may lie within the people who originally setup the Git repos, as opposed to an issue with SourceTree itself.